Setting Interior Color in a cell in excel
I am trying to colour the interior of cells in an excel spreadsheet. I want to set a colour which I am deriving from a routine based on a "NoteNum". This is just a number from a sequence from 1 to about 1600. The routine takes various actions and then returns an RGB value. This is performing exactly as I expect. It is producing rgb values that are all slightly different so that I can have a large range of colour values.
However, when these values are applied to the cells, they are not producing the range of colours. Instead, blocks of cells all have the same colour - all the same approximation to the shade that I am specifying.
I have recorded a macro setting colours manually using the More Colors->Custom options. doing the job manually does produce the range of colours that I would like. The code I have used is based on what the macro has produced.
Code used:
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 1 To 80
        col = GetColour(i)
        .Cells(i, 1).Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
        .Cells(i, 1).Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Cells(i, 1).Interior.TintAndShade = 0
        .Cells(i, 1).Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
        .Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = col
    Next i
End With

For reference, GetColour is:
Public Function GetColour(NoteNum As Long) As Variant
    Dim s As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim g As Integer
    Dim o As Integer
    
    s = Int(NoteNum Mod 80)
    o = Int(s / 80)
    
    r = (s + 0 Mod 80) + 175
    b = ((s + 33 + o * 2) Mod 80) + 175
    g = ((s + 66 + o * 3) Mod 80) + 175
    
    GetColour = RGB(r, g, b)
End Function

Here is a section of the output:

The numbers in the first three columns are the individual r,g,b integers; the number in column 4 is the RGB returned by GetColour.
For reference, the following code produces the expected result with the different shades being properly produced.
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, 5).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = RGB(201, 187, 234)
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, 5).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = RGB(191, 177, 224)
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

Can anyone help with why the code executed in the loop is not producing the correct results!

I think maybe those colours are different but the difference is subtle as your values in the loop only change by one.

You could be correct - I'll change the GetColour routine o try making a bigger difference ...

The colours  are different. You added 175 to everything so they are very small variations apart from where unintended overflows occur when there is a sudden jump 13-14, 46-47 79-80.

Thank you! Apologies for asking about something I should have spotted. Getting good results now ...

(The 175 was to ensure that the colours produced are at the lighter end of the scale. Played around with some factors to get better ranges. Thank you for the help.)

The colours you generated are all very slightly different - too close to tell in most cases unless there is an overflow. This routine at least generates shades that are far apart locally but some are still uncomfortably close together between adjacent blocks. It is scaled to avoid overflows.
Public Function NewGetColour(NoteNum) As Variant
   Dim s As Integer
   Dim r As Integer
   Dim b As Integer
   Dim g As Integer

   s = NoteNum

   r = (s Mod 4) * 25 + 175
   b = ((s / 4) Mod 4) * 25 + 175
   g = (s / 64) * 25 + 175

   NewGetColour = RGB(r, g, b)
End Function

I see no merit in only having 80 shades if there are 1600 possible inputs for NoteNum you may as well give them each a distinct colour. Decreasing 175 to 128  and increasing 25 to 42 might give you colours that are all sufficiently different enough to be OK. You may have to play about with the parameters to get something pleasing. Or failing that generate a lookup table of tasteful colours that are nicely different.
